# Why can't I use a if statement inside of my express handlebars template?

Tags: node.js, express, handlebars.js, templating

I've recently began working on my first Express project and I chose to use Handlebars as my template language because I had some prior experience when creating Ghost blog themes.

I'm creating a login screen using Passport.js and connect-flash to send error messages to the user. I'm able to pass in the error messages as a handlebars helper just fine but when I attempt to include an if statement inside the handlebars template it is always false even when there is an error message.

Here's my code:

*login.js (route)*

```
app.route('/login')
    .get(function(req, res) {
        if (req.isAuthenticated()) {
            res.redirect('/');
        } else {
            res.render('login', {
                helpers: {
                    message: req.flash('loginMessage')
                }
            });
        }
    })
    .post(...);
```

*login.handlebars*

```
<form action="/login" method="post">
    <div>
        <label>Email</label>
        <input type="text" name="email">
    </div>
    <div>
        <label>Password</label>
        <input type="password" name="password"> 
    </div>
    <button type="submit">Log In</button>
</form>

{{#if message}}
    <p style="color: red">{{message}}</p>
{{/if}}
```

This works without the if statement:

```
<p style="color: red">{{message}}</p>
```

But I don't like the idea of having empty elements all over my html. Any help would be greatly appreciated as I'm sure I'm missing something very simple.

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe you must use a [subexpression](http://handlebarsjs.com/expressions.html#subexpressions) in order to invoke multiple helpers within a single mustache. The fix is as simple as adding parentheses:

```
{{#if (message)}}
    <p style="color: red">{{message}}</p>
{{/if}}
```

**Edit**

Note that the above assumes that the type of object at `helpers.message` is a function as the [Handlebars documentation](https://github.com/ericf/express-handlebars#helpers) states that helpers are functions. However, the [connect-flash documentation](https://github.com/jaredhanson/connect-flash) suggests that `req.flash('loginMessage')` will return an array. In this case, the result should not be assigned to a helper, but should be a regular value of the view model object:

```
res.render('login', {
    messages: req.flash('loginMessage')
});
```

Within our template, as `messages` is an array, we will have to lookup and access its 0th element:

```
{{#if (lookup messages 0)}}
    <p style="color: red">{{messages.[0]}}</p>
{{/if}}
```

Comment: By adding the parentheses I got a TypeError upon opening the page. Any ideas on why that may be happening?

Comment: I guess `req.flash('loginMessage')` does not return a function. If it's just a string, I don't think it makes any sense as a helper. Why not just make it a regular property of your view model data?

Comment: Yep that was it. I didn't notice that flash was returning an array. I just passed through `req.flash('signupMessage')[0]` as a helper. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

This is probably coming way toooooo late, but for those who will still encounter this or related problem in the future, I hope this works for you.
Another way you could do it is to use `res.redirect('/login');` instead of `res.render('login)`.

Add this to your SERVER/INDEX.JS

```
const flash = require('connect-flash');//import this guy
    app.use(flash());
    app.use(function(req, res, next) {
    res.locals.message = req.flash('loginMessage'); 
    next();
  });
```

Your LOGIN.JS will look like this

```
  app.route('/login')
   .get(function(req, res) {
     if (req.isAuthenticated()) {
        res.redirect('/');
        return;//you should always return if there's no more thing to do
     } else {
       req.flash('loginMessage', 'your message here');
       res.redirect('/login');
       return;//you should always return if there's no more thing to do
    };
  })
  .post(...);
```

The above approach makes it easier for you to reuse your messages. Eg., You can reuse the above message by just changing `req.flash('loginMessage', 'your message here');` to this `req.flash('loginMessage', 'another message here');` .

You can also reuse the entire message by moving all error and success messages inside a PARTIAL folder and then using it in all your other pages in your front-end by inserting this `{{>yourMessages}}` in all the pages.

your LOGIN.handlebars

```
 <form action="/login" method="post">
   <div>
    <label>Email</label>
    <input type="text" name="email">
   </div>
   <div>
    <label>Password</label>
    <input type="password" name="password"> 
   </div>
   <button type="submit">Log In</button>
 </form>

 {{#if message}}
  <p style="color: red">{{message}}</p>
 {{/if}}
```